# Woocommerce - обновление способов доставки

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

В магазине на Woocommerce в оформлении заказа меняются способы доставки при изменении выбора в селекте "Область / район *", в админке это Зоны доставки.
Но проблема в том что они меняются только если заполнены поля Адрес, Населенный пункт и Почтовый индекс.
Населенный пункт индекс вообще не нужные поля, но если их убрать через плагины либо функции, тогда смена способов доставки вообще не работает.
Как сделать чтобы они менялись только при выборе "Область/район"

Comment: а если их сделать необязательными? ну будут в бд писать пустые значения, ну костыль, а что поделать :D

Comment: пробовал и через плагин и через функции - тогда способы доставки вообще не меняются, как будто эти поля пустые

Comment: а если в бд изменить их свойства?

Comment: каким образом?.

Comment: через мэнэджер бд, аля пхпмайадмин

Comment: Хотя, подождите, если сделал необязательными - вроде сработало, это я если их полностью скрывал не работало

Comment: ну вот :) карму не забудь :D